# CURL https give an error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am having trouble with this function. It works well with `http` but doesn't return anything when using `https`. I am working on facebook's url to fetch all public groups post.

```
function fetchUrl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

     $retData = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch); 

     return $retData;
}
```

The only way I've seen is to scrape the url by simple php html dom parser and convert it into array. However, I feel there's a better way, or could make some changes to this existing function. Where am I going wrong?

FYI: I have enabled openSSL in php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these options

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Quoting PHP Manual

> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST: 1 to check the existence of a common name in
>   the SSL peer certificate. 2 to check the existence of a common name
>   and also verify that it matches the hostname provided.
>
> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER: FALSE to stop CURL from verifying the peer's
>   certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified
>   with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be
>   specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST may
>   also need to be TRUE or FALSE if CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is disabled
>   (it defaults to 2).

Comment: Yes.. i see what was missing thank you for briefing saving a day. @Hanky Panky ㇱ